# Jquery Uncaught object angular.js:3650

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I refer below easy-pie-chart example and i downloaded it.

http://rendro.github.io/easy-pie-chart/

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>

    <link href="~/Content/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/canvas.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/easypiechart.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/easypiechart.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="angular" ng-controller="chartCtrl">
        <span class="chart" easypiechart ng-init="options = { animate:false, barColor:'#E67E22', scaleColor:false, lineWidth:3, lineCap:'butt' }" percent="percent" options="options">
            <span class="percent" ng-bind="percent"></span>
        </span>
        <input type="range" min="-100" max="100" step="1" ng-model="percent" />
        <span class="chart" easypiechart percent="anotherPercent" options="anotherOptions">
            <span class="percent" ng-bind="percent"></span>
        </span>
        <input type="range" min="-100" max="100" step="1" ng-model="anotherPercent" />
    </div>



    <script>
        var app = angular.module('app', ['easypiechart']);
        app.controller('chartCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.percent = 65;
            $scope.anotherPercent = -45;
            $scope.anotherOptions = {
                animate: {
                    duration: 0,
                    enabled: false
                },
                barColor: '#2C3E50',
                scaleColor: false,
                lineWidth: 20,
                lineCap: 'circle'
            };
        }]);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edited:**

I only run above code however i get below error

```
Uncaught object angular.js:3650
```

**Error Image:**
[image]

Where i miss exactly?

I tried to change position of script files however it did not solve the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Where you are included angularjs?

Comment: Where is your reference to angularjs library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi can you see this link once, this may solve your problem, the order of importing angular and easypiechart cause the error

https://github.com/rendro/easy-pie-chart

Comment: thanks this is the solution i dont know why it does not work in my code but your link was good and worked

Answer (score 2):

You need to include `AnugularJS` in your **html** like this :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/EoytKfJxqQqmpa08D2pj?p=preview)

Comment: thanks for answer but it does not work i get angular.js error

Comment: Dude just add the link provided by @EpokK above your others script tags !

Comment: @user3705822 check my DEMO and valid my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

May be you are missing the angular js file..

add this in your head section, and try...

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i added and i get Uncaught object angular.js:3650 error

Comment: add https also for Uncaught object angular.js:3650 error

Comment: Hi can you see this link once, this may solve your problem 

https://github.com/rendro/easy-pie-chart

the order of importing angular and easypiechart cause the error.